# Generate image in particular colormap in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a grayscale image in Matlab that I want to convert to an RGB image. To plot it I can simply do

```
imagesc(img)
colormap jet
```

or replace `colormap jet` with any other colormap. How would I get the actual array of RGB values that would give the equivalent image if I were to do `image(img)`?

Comment: Do you have the Image Processing Toolbox? If so, [`ind2rgb`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/ind2rgb.html) has this covered.

Comment: That works. One note, though, the image needs to be rescaled to be in the integer range between 1 and 64, if you just pass it a default-sized colormap. For instance, `img = ceil(64*mat2gray(img))` would accomplish this.

Comment: That, or generate a colormap of the appropriate size e.g. `jet(256);` It might be more convenient to scale a `double` image to [0 1] then use `gray2ind` first.